# Can i use jQuery .load while still changing URL?

Tags: php, jquery, templates, wordpress

**What i want to achieve**

I want to be able to shift seamlessly through the different posts in the sidebar on [this](http://ap-pe.dk) website, while having using a custom post template for my posts. And by seamlessly i mean that the screen doesn't go white for a second every time you navigate it.

**My problem**

single.php or single-{slug}.php does not work, since the URL doesn't change while navigating the sidebar

**Plugins i am using**

Custom Post Type UI

Ajax Content Renderer

**jQuery script for my sidebar**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sidebar li:has(a)").click(function() {

        var page = $("a:first",this).attr("href");

        $("#content").load(page);
        return false;
    });
});
```

**HTML & PHP for sidebar and content area**

```
<div class="row"> <!-- Main content row -->
    <div class="col-md-4" id="sidebar">
        <?php
        if (is_page('gulvservice')){
            wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'gulvservice' ));
        } elseif (is_page('malerservice')) {
            wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'malerservice' ));
        } elseif (is_page('industrilakering')) {
            wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'industrilakering' ));
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8" id="content">
        <?php  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="title"><h1>
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h1></div>
            <div class="div">
                <?php
                if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div> <!-- Main Content -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to prevent the event on the `<a>`. So it would be better to move the selector to those elements

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sidebar li a").click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#content").load(page);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: I cannot believe it was that easy. However it caused another problem (obviously), that the `li` itself isn't clickable anymore, which is what is intended. Do you know a fix for this?

Comment: try adding `event` argument and instead of `return false` use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Thank you, i will try that!